# Invalid setting error when connecting to phpMyAdmin in XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10 but cannot open phpMyAdmin. I had to change Apache and MySQL ports to `8088` and `3307` because of conflicts and now they are both running. When I click on phpMyAdmin on my server it gives me the following message in a pink box:

> Error MySQL said: Cannot connect: invalid settings

I've read the questions on similar problems but they mostly happened when someone changed the password, but for my case, the user is set to root and the password is empty both in MySQL server connection and in the `config.inc.php` file. I have no clue where to look for the problem. I'm running PHP Version 5.6.12.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193713/change-port-of-mysql-server-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the connection settings as outlined in the [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_port)?

> If you use `localhost` as the hostname, MySQL ignores this port number
>   and connects with the socket, so if you want to connect to a port
>   different from the default port, use `127.0.0.1` or the real hostname in
>   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']`.

Comment: added the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307' ` and it got fixed.