# acess denied while using PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10 but cannot open phpMyAdmin. I had to change mysql port 3306 to 3308 as it was required from our professor and now both apache and mysql are running. When I click on phpMyAdmin on my server it gives me the following message in a pink box:

Bienvenue dans phpMyAdmin

Erreur MySQL a répondu : Documentation

Connexion impossible : paramètres incorrects.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée
La connexion au « controluser » telle que définie dans la configuration a échoué.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée
phpMyAdmin a tenté de se connecter au serveur MySQL, et le serveur a rejeté la connexion. Merci de vérifier les valeurs de host, username et password dans la configuration et de s'assurer qu'elles correspondent aux informations fournies par l'administrateur du serveur MySQL.

I've read the questions on similar problems but they mostly happened when someone changed the password, but for my case, the user is set to root and the password is empty both in MySQL server connection and in the config.inc.php file. I have no clue where to look for the problem.

Comment: Make sure that you can connect to the mysql server on the command line with port 3308, and that the correct port is in the phpmyadmin settings

Comment: [Change the port in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193713/change-port-of-mysql-server-in-phpmyadmin)